Mtg: attacking effect, but the creature dies
Neck Breaker (the transformed side of Breakneck Rider) gives attacking creatures +1/+0. If I attack and then a spell kills the Neck Breaker after I declared my attackers, does the effect remain on the other attacking creatures?

The effect ends.
This ability is a static ability (another example would be Warded Battlements), which means that the ability is only "active" as long as the permanent is on the battlefield. Comprehensive rules entry (emphasis mine):

604.1. Static abilities do something all the time rather than being activated or triggered. They are written as statements, and they’re simply true.
604.2. Static abilities create continuous effects, some of which are prevention effects or replacement effects. These effects are active as long as the permanent with the ability remains on the battlefield and has the ability, or as long as the object with the ability remains in the appropriate zone, as described in rule 113.6.

Answer done.
However, I want to touch on a similar scenario taking into account triggered abilities (instead of static abilities):
If the ability was a triggered ability (e.g. from Bolt Hound), then the effect would stay.
Triggered abilities are separate from the game objects that created them. In this instance, if the creature is removed when the trigger already went to the stack, it will still resolve normally. The only way to prevent this would be to remove the creature before the trigger condition happens.
As an example, if the condition is "At the beginning of combat on your turn", then the creature would need to be removed in the main phase before combat so the ability never triggers.
The related part of the Comprehensive Rules is (emphasis mine)

113.7a Once activated or triggered, an ability exists on the stack independently of its source. Destruction or removal of the source after that time won’t affect the ability. Note that some abilities cause a source to do something (for example, “Prodigal Pyromancer deals 1 damage to any target”) rather than the ability doing anything directly. In these cases, any activated or triggered ability that references information about the source for use while announcing an activated ability or putting a triggered ability on the stack checks that information when the ability is put onto the stack. Otherwise, it will check that information when it resolves. In both instances, if the source is no longer in the zone it’s expected to be in at that time, its last known information is used. The source can still perform the action even though it no longer exists.


I'm glad. :) If that worked for you, you can mark the question as "solved" by accepting the answer by clicking the check mark on the left of the answer with the voting buttons.

Agreed with @PhilipKendall the effect looks like it comes from a static ability that would disappear with the creature it's on.

agree as well and I have updated the answer. For now I will leave the answer covering both scenarios (static and triggered abilities), but will change if the question is clarified.

If anyone has a better part from the CR to show this aspect of static abilities, I'll gladly include that.

@fxm the rule you want for static abilities is 604.2, the one with the words "[...]These effects are active as long as the permanent with the ability remains on the battlefield and has the ability, or as long as the object with the ability remains in the appropriate zone[...]"

overlooked that, thanks!

@PhilipKendall I think this search is more comprehensive and gives me 9 static, 10 triggered abilities that give +1/+0 to attacking creatures.

@PhilipKendall Oh yes true, forgot about that. Taking that into account it leaves me with 7 hits, 3 static 4 triggered, so same ratio basically.

@Hackworth there are only 2 triggers in that result, Honored Crop-Captain and Targ Nar. The rest, on the permanents at least, are static or activated abilities, though the activated abilities, like the triggers, will still work if the creature is removed.

Too clarify, because I’m new in mtg. I played the Werwolf version from the card [[breakneck rider]], so the [[neck breaker]] and if I understood it right, the effect is gone because it ain’t a triggered effect, it’s a static effect? I hope I understood everything correct.

@Steve For Neck Breaker the effect ends, that's a static effect, not a triggered (or activated) ability

The answer should be updated to reflect the clarified question. "It depends" is no longer a valid answer to the question as written now.

In general, a question is not supposed to be edited in a way that invalidates existing answers, and if it does happen, the poster of an answer has no obligation to edit their answer to accommodate the change in the question. The usual way of handling this is to revert the change to the question. (But I suppose if fxm would like to edit their answer, there's no reason they couldn't.)

I really appreciate the answers, they really helped me understand my deck more. Thank you too all people discussing about the question.
